# Kafka Connect JsonConverter with validation

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to create kafka connect value converter which wraps invalid json records with a valid json object.

I'm reading the values from kinesis (using KinesisSourceConnector) so the input is in base64 encoding.

My implementation tries to process the input through ByteArrayConverter which decodes the data amd delegate the output to JsonConverter as follows (*decode* is initialized in the configure method to true):

```
private final Converter delegate = new JsonConverter();
    private final Converter decoder = new ByteArrayConverter();
    private boolean decode = false;

    @Override
    public byte[] fromConnectData(String topic, Schema schema, Object value) {
        try {
            String decoded = new String(decoder.fromConnectData(topic, schema, value));
            LOG.info("decoded string\n" + decoded);

            if(decode) {
                byte[] bytes = decoder.fromConnectData(topic, schema, value);
                return delegate.fromConnectData(topic, schema, bytes);
            }
            return delegate.fromConnectData(topic, schema, value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("something went wrong", e);
            return delegate.fromConnectData(topic, schema, wrapInvalidJson(new String(decoder.fromConnectData(topic, schema, value))));
        }
    }
```

When i am printing the decoded string it looks ok (decoded json string)

But when i consume the output topic it looks like base64 again and I'm not sure what i am missing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is optimal but went for this approache

```
    private final Converter delegate = new JsonConverter();
    private final Converter decoder = new ByteArrayConverter();
    private final Converter stringConverter = new StringConverter();
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private boolean decode = false;

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        delegate.configure(Collections.singletonMap("schemas.enable", false), false);
        if (configs.containsKey("ni.decode.data") && Boolean.valueOf((String) configs.get("ni.decode.data"))) {
            decode = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] fromConnectData(String topic, Schema schema, Object value) {

        if (decode) {
            String decoded = new String(decoder.fromConnectData(topic, schema, value));
            try {
                return mapper.readTree(decoded).toString().getBytes();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return wrapInvalidJson(decoded).getBytes();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                return delegate.fromConnectData(topic, schema, value);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                byte[] msg = stringConverter.fromConnectData(topic, schema, value);
                return wrapInvalidJson(new String(msg)).getBytes();
            }
        }
    }
```